# Laravel 5.1 + phpsysinfo - how?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm currently experimenting with Laravel 5.1

I want to display realtime resource usage and thus I found [phpsysinfo](https://github.com/phpsysinfo/phpsysinfo). I've required it into my project via composer and I'm able to run and view a working version by viewing phpsysinfo's root directory.

How do I actually then start displaying this on my `/public` pages ? I can't see any type of syntax on phpsysinfo's documentation.

Comment: Did you already add a class Alias to the app.php file? Because all you have to do is to use the namespace in any of your controllers and send an object to your views

Comment: Well I thought I had to do that but I'm not sure what the path would be exactly? the file structure for all of Laravel's Aliases is completely different to the structure of Phpsysinfo

Comment: Edit: forget it, I'm checking the github repo

Comment: I'm pretty sure I could AJAX to it but I'd prefer not to

Comment: If I had a project, in which I had to integrate it with laravel, I would install the phpsysinfo as a standalone app and use a restfull webservice to get the data. Can you do that? or do you want to definitely install it inside your laravel as a practice or requirement?

Comment: Well basically I've got an admin template that has dummy 'resource usage' panels and my goal is to hook it up to real values. Out of the two options you asked, which would be better? Or is it simply down to preference?

Comment: I'm not a laravel expert, I work with it, but I don't consider myself and expert, but... There are two options for me. The webservice way I mentioned, or... putting it inside the app directory and creating a namespace and a class, in which you INCLUDE the phpsysinfo autoload and create methods to get the data from it, then use thos methods in your controllers, and views.. what do you think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92579/discussion-between-ashley-brown-and-juan-bonnett).